# Determining if a website is a web-store or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to determine if a website from a list of websites if a web-store or not.

It seems that *most* web-stores have:

- An `a` tag with the word 'cart' in their `href`
- An `li` tag assigned to a class with the word 'cart' in the class name

I believe I would have to take advantage of regular expressions, then tell the BeautifulSoup `find` method to search the HTML data for this regular expression in an `a` or `li` tag. How should I go about this?

So far, the code below searches the HTML data for an `a` tag with an `href` of EXACTLY cart.

**Code**

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

websites = [
    'https://www.nike.com/',
    'https://www.youtube.com/',
    'https://www.google.com/',
    'https://www.amazon.com/',
    'https://www.gamestop.com/'
]
shops = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('log-level=3')

with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    for url in websites:
        driver.get(url)
        cart = re.compile('.*cart.*', re.IGNORECASE)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        if soup.find('a', href=cart):
            shops.append(url)

print('\nSHOPS FOUND:')
for shop in shops:
    print(shop)
```

**Output:**

```
SHOPS FOUND:
https://www.nike.com/
https://www.amazon.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use contains * operator with css attribute selectors to specify class attribute or href attribute contains substring cart. Combine the two (class and href) with Or syntax. TODO: You might consider adding wait conditions to ensure all `li` and `a` tag elements are present first.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

websites = [
    'https://www.nike.com/',
    'https://www.youtube.com/',
    'https://www.google.com/',
    'https://www.amazon.com/',
    'https://www.gamestop.com/'
]
shops = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('log-level=3')

with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    for url in websites:
        driver.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        items = soup.select('a[href*=cart], li[class*=cart]')
        if len(items) > 0:
                shops.append(url)
print('\nSHOPS FOUND:')
for shop in shops:
    print(shop)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It seems to be working with other websites as well.

One question, it doesn't return 'GameStop' as a store. However, upon inspecting GameStop's HTML, [there is clearly an `li` tag with a class of 'cart`](https://imgur.com/b6429cbc-a4bc-4610-9f55-6ae93bd6c8ef). I wonder why this can be.

Comment: Hi, for some reason I didn't see this response. I cannot currently access that url. Can you include the html for that page using https://pastebin.com/ . I will then have a look.

Comment: The selector is correct but I am being denied access to that server. If you run without headless can you actually see the page content with selenium + chrome?